# Fourier Transform of a compactly supported distribution : how to write the definition in a "better way"?

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I am really troubled by the following Theorem :

*Theorem : If $u\in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb R^d)$ (space of compactly supported distributions), then its Fourier transform is a function, and :
**$\hat{u}(\xi)=\langle u,e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\rangle$**

For a distribution of $u\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb R),$ we define the Fourier transform of $u$ as a **distribution**, defined for all $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$ by $\langle\hat u,\phi\rangle=\langle u, \hat\phi \rangle$

Moreover $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb R^d) \subset \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb R^d)$.

So.. If I follow the definition that is given to me I'm supposed to have, for $u \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb R^d),$ $\hat{u}$ as a distribution.

Edit : **Evaluating $\hat{u}$ in a real or complex number then doesn't make any sense to me. A distribution of this type has a Schwartz function as argument , and not a complex number to my opinion. So I don't understand how can the symbolism "$\hat{u}(\xi)"$ have a sense in the theorem ? It can also simply be a misunderstanding on my part of the rôle of $\hat{u}$,**

A bit stuck with this. Also, if it's just a notation problem, I'd also be interested on how you can easily understand/read this theorem, as this makes a nonsense to me.

Comment: See my edits to this question for proper MathJax usage.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, or where your confusion is. Could you please rephrase and emphasize where you are confused, or where you see some sort of contradiction?

Comment: Thanks for answering , tried to edit , problem in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributional Fourier transform of $u \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is by definition a distribution. But there is a function $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\hat{u}$ is given by integration against $f,$ i.e.
$$\langle \hat{u}, \varphi \rangle = \int f(\xi)\,\varphi(\xi)\,d\xi.$$
What the theorem says is that $f(\xi)=\langle u(x), e^{-ix\cdot\xi} \rangle.$

Comment: Thanks ! Also , i think the x in the last line means to precise in which variable we want to "use in the distribution formula". I also tried to write it with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying it : (To be confirmed)

Meaning of the theorem : There exists a $L_1^\text{Loc}(R^d)$ function , such as $\hat{u}$=$T_f$ and :

$$\forall \varphi \in D(R^d),\langle\hat{u},\varphi\rangle=\langle T_f, \varphi \rangle, \text{ where } f:\xi \rightarrow \langle u,e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\rangle$$

So for example , if $u$ is a compactly supported distribution , Let's say $u=T_g$ then :

\begin{align}
& \forall \varphi \in D(R^d),\,\langle\hat{u},\varphi\rangle=\langle T_f,\varphi\rangle \\[6pt]
= {} & \int \langle u,e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\rangle \varphi(\xi) \, d\xi \\[6pt]
= {} & \int \varphi(\xi)\int g(x) e^{-ix\cdot\xi} \, dx \,d\xi
\end{align}

Comment: Note that proper MathJax usage is $\langle\hat{u},\varphi\rangle=\langle T_f, \varphi \rangle,$ not $<\hat{u},\varphi> = <T_f, \varphi >.$ And $x\cdot\xi,$ not $x.\xi.$ You can google "latex symbols" to find things like these.